# Can you stop a window.onload function?

Tags: javascript, click, onload, skip

I implemented a sequential fade triggered by `window.onload`

I want to know if I can stop it from executing midway or wherever it currently is and show everything at once using `...style.display = "inline-block";` for everything that was going to be faded in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have used,

```
function init()
{
}
window.onload = init;
```

**Stop it!**
That line of code will completely wipe out any other functions that were attached and ready to handle the `onload` event. How arrogant of your script to do so! ;)

Instead, your script should learn to play nicely. Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support the delegate syntax that `C#` has.
Yes, there is a way to achieve that :

### First Way:

```
function highlightXFNLinks()
{
  // Does stuff...
}

//
// Adds event to window.onload without overwriting currently 
// assigned onload functions.
function addLoadEvent(func)
{    
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function')
    {
        window.onload = func;
    } 
    else 
    {
        window.onload = function()
        {
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}

addLoadEvent(highlightXFNLinks);

window.onload += init;
```

### Second Way:

Better than first one...

```
function AddOnload(myfunc)
{
    if(window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener('load', myfunc, false);
    else if(window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent('onload', myfunc);
}
```

Comment: it is never easy is it? I'll try this out, thanks a lot

Comment: If you get clear with **Core** concept, then it's as easy as English!

Comment: Yeah I guess I'm not getting the "**Core**" concept. I'm sort of losing interest in this partially because I don't understand but also because I think this sequential fading maybe annoying and it may not be intuitive to people to tap the screen / click to skip. I have to design things assuming a really dumb audience for larger targeting but whatever... anyway thank you for your response.